# Problem running Tensorflow (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu, nvidia

I've recently tried to install and run some python and tensorflow code from [this](https://github.com/Fyusion/LLFF/) repository.

I followed the manual installation procedure just as mentioned in the README.md present in the repository.

As I've never used tensorflow before, I had to install a lot of packages to get it up and running.

Currently, I've got tensorfow-gpu 1.13, python 3.7, and an Nvidia graphics card (mx250) on my Ubuntu 19.10 laptop, and I wish to get the code running. However, I'm having issues running the `demo.sh` file present with it.

Here's what I get in the err.txt when I run the command `$ bash demo.sh > output.txt 2> err.txt` at the cloned directory (after installing all required packages):

```
*** Aborted at 1575094215 (unix time) try "date -d @1575094215" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7f92c7012ae8 ceres::internal::ProgramEvaluator<>::Evaluate()
*** SIGSEGV (@0x0) received by PID 22202 (TID 0x7f92acda5700) from PID 0; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f92c7452641 (unknown)
    @     0x7f92c67dd540 (unknown)
    @     0x7f92c7012ae8 ceres::internal::ProgramEvaluator<>::Evaluate()
    @     0x7f92c709265f ceres::internal::TrustRegionMinimizer::EvaluateGradientAndJacobian()
    @     0x7f92c7092f4a ceres::internal::TrustRegionMinimizer::IterationZero()
    @     0x7f92c70972d4 ceres::internal::TrustRegionMinimizer::Minimize()
    @     0x7f92c7088cbc ceres::Solver::Solve()
    @     0x7f92c70899b9 ceres::Solve()
    @     0x55bb3bb1a2eb colmap::BundleAdjuster::Solve()
    @     0x55bb3bb78037 colmap::IncrementalMapper::AdjustGlobalBundle()
    @     0x55bb3bac3f0c (unknown)
    @     0x55bb3bac521d colmap::IncrementalMapperController::Reconstruct()
    @     0x55bb3bac6a9b colmap::IncrementalMapperController::Run()
    @     0x55bb3bbd7dfc colmap::Thread::RunFunc()
    @     0x7f92c5ad9f74 (unknown)
    @     0x7f92c67d1669 start_thread
    @     0x7f92c578f323 clone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imgs2poses.py", line 11, in <module>
    gen_poses(args.scenedir)
  File "/home/abhigyan/Code/CVProject/LLFF/llff/poses/pose_utils.py", line 265, in gen_poses
    run_colmap(basedir)
  File "/home/abhigyan/Code/CVProject/LLFF/llff/poses/colmap_wrapper.py", line 70, in run_colmap
    map_output = ( subprocess.check_output(mapper_args, universal_newlines=True) )
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['colmap', 'mapper', '--database_path', 'data/testscene/database.db', '--image_path', 'data/testscene/images', '--output_path', 'data/testscene/sparse', '--Mapper.num_threads', '16', '--Mapper.init_min_tri_angle', '4', '--Mapper.multiple_models', '0', '--Mapper.extract_colors', '0']' died with <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imgs2mpis.py", line 10, in <module>
    from llff.inference.mpi_utils import run_inference
  File "/home/abhigyan/Code/CVProject/LLFF/llff/inference/mpi_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from llff.inference.mpi_tester import DeepIBR
  File "/home/abhigyan/Code/CVProject/LLFF/llff/inference/mpi_tester.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘data/testscene/outputs/’: File exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imgs2renderpath.py", line 34, in <module>
    poses, bds = load_data(args.scenedir, load_imgs=False)
  File "/home/abhigyan/Code/CVProject/LLFF/llff/poses/pose_utils.py", line 195, in load_data
    poses_arr = np.load(os.path.join(basedir, 'poses_bounds.npy'))
  File "/home/abhigyan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 428, in load
    fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/testscene/poses_bounds.npy'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
demo.sh: line 24: 22221 Aborted                 (core dumped) cuda_renderer/cuda_renderer data/testscene/mpis_360 data/testscene/outputs/test_path.txt data/testscene/outputs/test_vid.mp4 360 .8 18
```

Comment: what version of CUDA do you have? It looks like that error is related to CUDA.

Comment: @oktogen ```Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.168```. Also, how did you figure out that it's related to CUDA? I've been trying to figure out for a long time, but I didn't realise

Comment: Tensorflow is not compatible with CUDA version 10.1, you have few options, downgrade CUDA to 10.0, compile tensorflow by yourself with CUDA 10.1 or find some wheel on github, for example here https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues Thanks to the line: ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are going to use Tensorflow in GPU setup, have to carefully install and configure the Tensorflow in your machine. I would like to prefer to use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version instead of 19.xx.

Follow the installation steps from the blog: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/49166211